# software for drawing graphs (trees)

Tags: math-software

Sorry if I misunderstand if I can ask this type of questions in here.
I would like to know names of free softwares (preferably online) where I could draw graphs like the ones on the image.

Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06037.pdf

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The most common tool is Tikz. It has a learning curve, but once you get the hang of it you can easily copy-paste instructions to easily get many variant images like in Figure 2.

Comment: Yes. I believe we can close this question now. Thank you

Comment: You might also be interested in [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/).